# Archiving Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm very new to shell script and I'm having issues with archiving files.

I have a folder with .xlsm files and I want those files that passed the retention period. I was able to archive except I'm having issues with those files having spaces with their filename eg. X y z.xlsm. below is my sample code.

```
find ${work_dir} -type f -mtime +${retention} | xargs tar -cvf ${Destination}/archive.tar
```

Any idea how to achieve it?
Thanks!

Comment: I assume `+{retention}` was supposed to be `+${retention}`? Also, `Find` should be `find` — as `bash` is not case-insensitive.

Comment: Hi thank u for responding yes you are correct just typo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use NUL as delimiter (`-print0` for `find`, and `--null` for `xargs`).

```
find ${work_dir} -type f -mtime +${retention} -print0 | xargs --null tar -cvf ${Destination}/archive.tar
```